# How to calculate a speed for slideToggle()

Tags: javascript, jquery, slidetoggle, jquery-easing

I have a navigation menu with several accordion-style items. Some "parent" links have more children than others. I'd like to vary the speed of the `slideToggle()` so that the ones with more children take longer to `slideDown()`. Here is what I tried, but it's jumping around for some reason. There's no easing happening at all, as you can see.

```js
// Get the height of each list and save it in the data-height attribute
$('.main-nav > ul > li > ul').each(function() {
  $(this).slideDown(0);
  $(this).data('height', $(this).height());
  $(this).slideUp(0);
});

$('.main-nav > ul > li').click(function() {
  // Multiply the height of the element by the speed desired
  $(this).children().slideToggle($(this).data('height') * 1000, 'easeInOutExpo');
});
```

```css
.main-nav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.main-nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 18px;
}
.main-nav ul li {
  padding: 22px 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.main-nav > ul {
  padding: 0 22px;
}
.main-nav > ul > li > ul {
  display: none;
}
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.3/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
<nav class="main-nav">
  <ul>
    <li>Global
      <ul>
        <li>Typography</li>
        <li>Colors</li>
        <li>Icons</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Elements
      <ul>
        <li>Text</li>
        <li>Buttons</li>
        <li>Lists</li>
        <li>Tables</li>
        <li>Media</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Controls
      <ul>
        <li>dropdown</li>
        <li>alerts</li>
        <li>badges</li>
        <li>modals</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Layout
      <ul>
        <li>dynamic row</li>
        <li>flex</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Components
      <ul>
        <li>cards</li>
        <li>banners</li>
        <li>itemEditor</li>
        <li>itemIndex</li>
        <li>jQueryUI</li>
        <li>login</li>
        <li>main</li>
        <li>details (and detail views)</li>
        <li>drilldown</li>
        <li>mega menu</li>
        <li>navigation</li>
        <li>search</li>
        <li>thick items</li>
        <li>widgets</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: How about something like this `$(this).children().length * 1000` instead of `$(this).data('height') * 1000`?

Comment: That's a great idea, @imtheman! Thanks so much!

Comment: @imtheman Hmmm, that's returning "1".

Comment: Ah yes, I didn't realize that the click was on the parent `li`. I've added an answer with the correct way to do it (for this way at least).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of going based off height, I'd recommend going based off how many `li` elements are in the `ul` (you may need to modify the multiplier if 1000 is too slow for you).

```js
// Get the height of each list and save it in the data-height attribute
$('.main-nav > ul > li > ul').each(function() {
  $(this).slideUp(0);
});

$('.main-nav > ul > li').click(function() {
  // Multiply the height of the element by the speed desired
  $(this).children().slideToggle($(this).find("li").length * 1000, 'easeInOutExpo');
});
```

```css
.main-nav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.main-nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 18px;
}
.main-nav ul li {
  padding: 22px 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.main-nav > ul {
  padding: 0 22px;
}
.main-nav > ul > li > ul {
  display: none;
}
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.3/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
<nav class="main-nav">
  <ul>
    <li>Global
      <ul>
        <li>Typography</li>
        <li>Colors</li>
        <li>Icons</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Elements
      <ul>
        <li>Text</li>
        <li>Buttons</li>
        <li>Lists</li>
        <li>Tables</li>
        <li>Media</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Controls
      <ul>
        <li>dropdown</li>
        <li>alerts</li>
        <li>badges</li>
        <li>modals</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Layout
      <ul>
        <li>dynamic row</li>
        <li>flex</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Components
      <ul>
        <li>cards</li>
        <li>banners</li>
        <li>itemEditor</li>
        <li>itemIndex</li>
        <li>jQueryUI</li>
        <li>login</li>
        <li>main</li>
        <li>details (and detail views)</li>
        <li>drilldown</li>
        <li>mega menu</li>
        <li>navigation</li>
        <li>search</li>
        <li>thick items</li>
        <li>widgets</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

`$(this).data('height')` appears to be undefined, so it appears that you end up passing `NaN` as the first arg to the `slideToggle()` function, I am not sure what the fix is but hopefully that points you in the right direction